# Determine the value of y so that two line segments are parallel

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> Determine the value of $y$ so that the line segment with endpoints $P(3, y)$ and $Q(-3, -1)$ is parallel to the line segment with endpoints $R(-4, 9)$ and $S(5,6)$.

I began by finding the slope of the second segment: 
$$\frac{6-9}{5-(-4)}=\frac{-3}{-9}$$ I don't what to do from here, or if I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: 6-9/5-(-4)=-3/-9 I don't what to do from here.. or if I'm supposed to do this..

Comment: Do you know what parallel means in regards to the gradients of two lines?

Comment: no..... i dont even know what gradients mean??

Comment: He means slopes. See my answer below. And you have a sign error in the denominator, I think. The slope of $RS$ should be $-1/3$, right?

Comment: yes i think so.

Comment: Well, then do the same thing with the other pair, and set the slopes equal to each other. That's saying they are parallel. That gives an equation in $y$, which you can solve for $y$. Don't worry that there is a "$y$" instead of a number. Just think of the "$y$" as holding the place for a number that you are going to determine. Use the symbol as a number and compute the slope the same way.

Comment: Also, you can find the value geometrically as follows. Plot the points $R$ and $S$. Draw the line $\mathscr L$ through $R$ and $S$. Plot the point $Q$. Draw the line $\mathscr M$ through $Q$ that is parallel to $\mathscr L$. Draw the vertical line $\mathscr N$ at $x=3$. The lines $\mathscr M$ and $\mathscr N$ meet at $P$. $y$ is the vertical coordinate of $P$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** What you computed is part of what you need, but you should attack the problem by asking: "What is a mathematical formulation of the problem?"

You should then think, "I know two lines are parallel if and only if their slopes are equal (or both undefined)."

So if you compute the slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ of the lines containing these segments, and equate them, you will have a statement that formulates the problem.

With luck, this will be an equation you can solve for the unknown quantity $y$.

**Hint 2:** The slope of $RS$ is $-1/3$. The slope of $PQ$ is $(y+1)/6$.

**Hint 3:** Set the slopes from the previous hint equal to each other and solve for $y$ (which is what the problem asks you to find).